# HashMap on inserting previously stored values are been over written

Tags: java, hashmap

I have created a HashMap and when tried to insert values at the location greater than the size of the map, previously stored values are been over written and lost.

```
Map<Integer, String> myTestObj = new HashMap<Integer,String>();

myTestObj.put(0,"zero");
myTestObj.put(1,"one");
myTestObj.put(2,"two");
myTestObj.put(3,"three");
myTestObj.put(13,"thirteen");
myTestObj.put(14,"fourteen");
myTestObj.put(15,"fifteen");

myTestObj.put(16,"sixteen");
myTestObj.put(17,"senventeen");
```

Hash Map contents

**Actual output:**

[17=senventeen, 16=sixteen, 2=two, 3=three, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, 13=thirteen, 14=fourteen, 15=fifteen]

**Expected Output**
[0=zero, 1=one, 2=two, 3=three, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, 13=thirteen, 14=fourteen, 15=fifteen, 16=sixteen, 17=senventeen]

What is the reason for such behaviour?

Comment: Your code works as expected. I suspect that you have some code that messes things up.

Comment: Post a complete example that reproduces the problem.

Comment: How do you print the **Actual output**?

Comment: @mixel, I have posted my entire code. if you need more info please be specific.

Comment: @user2900314 no, you haven't. There is nothing in the posted code that print the map, so it doesn't produce any output. Post a **complete** example reproducing the problem. I must be able to copy your code, paste it in my IDE, press run, and have the problem reproduced.

Comment: @user2900314 I tested your code with `System.out.println(myTestObj)` in the end and it prints me `{0=zero, 16=sixteen, 1=one, 17=senventeen, 2=two, 3=three, 13=thirteen, 14=fourteen, 15=fifteen}` when I run it with Java 8, `{17=senventeen, 0=zero, 16=sixteen, 1=one, 2=two, 3=three, 13=thirteen, 14=fourteen, 15=fifteen}` with Java 7 and `{17=senventeen, 0=zero, 16=sixteen, 1=one, 2=two, 3=three, 13=thirteen, 14=fourteen, 15=fifteen}` with Java 6. There is no error.

Comment: @mixel, I was infact looking at a big chunk of code for my work, and I was debugging it. In the debug variables, its displayed like that. I tried replicaed the same as a sample problem and I am seeing the same result in debug. But when I printed out the result is as expected.  Sorry for wasting  you time.

Comment: Conclusion: there is a problem with your debugger ......  or maybe some other part of your application updated the map behind the debugger's back.

Comment: Hey ... I'm serious.  Debuggers can't always be relied on to give an accurate picture of what is going on.

Comment: @StephenC, I have learnt it in a hard way now, Now I am yet to figure out the problem and I have even given the delivery date based on my findings. Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I presume that you used `System.out.println(myTestObj)` or something like that to display the map.

In that case, you are relying on `HashMap.toString()` to format the object, and that is formatting the entries in natural iteration order.  The problem is that the natural iteration order of a `HashMap` is not defined.

If you want the map entries to be returned / displayed sorted on the keys, then use a `TreeMap`.  If you want the map to preserve the insertion order, used a `LinkedHashMap`.

---

> HashMap on inserting previously stored values are been over written

They are NOT being overwritten.  Or at least, not in the code that you have shown us.

What is happening is that they are being displayed in a different order to the order in which you inserted them ... which is consistent with the specification of `HashMap` an *unordered* map.

---

For the record:

```
[stephen@blackbox tmp]$ cat Test.java 
import java.util.*;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<Integer, String> myTestObj = new HashMap<Integer,String>();

        myTestObj.put(0,"zero");
        myTestObj.put(1,"one");
        myTestObj.put(2,"two");
        myTestObj.put(3,"three");
        myTestObj.put(13,"thirteen");
        myTestObj.put(14,"fourteen");
        myTestObj.put(15,"fifteen");

        myTestObj.put(16,"sixteen");
        myTestObj.put(17,"senventeen");

        System.out.println(myTestObj);
    }
}

[stephen@blackbox tmp]$ javac Test.java 
[stephen@blackbox tmp]$ java Test
{0=zero, 16=sixteen, 1=one, 17=senventeen, 2=two, 3=three, 13=thirteen, 14=fourteen, 15=fifteen}
[stephen@blackbox tmp]$
```

Conclusion: if objects are *really* being overwritten or removed, it is because of some code that you haven't shown us.

Comment: It's not about the insertion order. It's a question about the missing values `0, "zero"` and `1, "one"`.

Comment: I don't believe that is happening (elements are actually missing).  And if they are, then either it is a threading problem, or some other part of his program is removing the objects.

Comment: I was infact looking at a big chunk of code for my work, and I was debugging it. In the debug variables, its displayed like that. I tried replicaed the same as a sample problem and I am seeing the same result in debug. But when I printed out the result is as expected.  Sorry for wasting  you time.

Answer (score 1):

I have executed your code and I get the below output:
`{17=senventeen, 0=zero, 16=sixteen, 1=one, 2=two, 3=three, 13=thirteen,14=fourteen, 15=fifteen}`

HashMap is a data structure in which you are able to store key-value pairs. It essential that the key is unique. Otherwise you overwrite the value that has the same key. In your case all of your keys are unique so I do not think you will get the wrong output.